# CardSpaceException: No version of the CardSpace service was found to be installed on the machine

Tags: c#, .net, https, wsdl, cardspace

first of all, I don't have clue, what am I doing. I'm a Java dev and I have to fix a C# program somebody else wrote.

We had to update and move a web services to another machine. The update included a change to https.
The tool I have to fix is used to upload files to the web service and is running on the same machine as the service.
The communication is over SOAP (I think) using a wsdl file.
The SSL-certificate is self signed but stored in the trusted cert storage.

First I tried to just change the paths to the new server but the upload tool complained about the change to https. Unfortunately, I don't have the exception anymore.

Then I re-imported the new wsdl and now I'm getting:

> System.IdentityModel.Selectors.CardSpaceException: No version of the CardSpace service was found to be installed on the machine. Please install CardSpace and retry the operation.
>
> Server stack trace:    at
> System.IdentityModel.Selectors.CardSpaceShim.GetCardSpaceImplementationDll()
> at
> System.IdentityModel.Selectors.CardSpaceShim.InitializeIfNecessary()
> at
> System.IdentityModel.Selectors.CardSpaceSelector.GetToken(CardSpacePolicyElement[]
> policyChain, SecurityTokenSerializer tokenSerializer)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials.GetInfoCardSecurityToken(Boolean
> requiresInfoCard, CardSpacePolicyElement[] chain,
> SecurityTokenSerializer tokenSerializer)    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
> md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
> msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:    at
> System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
> at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.DisplayInitializationUI()
> at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallDisplayUIOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel
> channel, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan
> timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureDisplayUI()    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
> methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [1]:    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type)    at
> CLIIkarosImport.ImportUploadService.IImportUploadService.UploadFile(FileUploadMessage
> request)    at
> CLIIkarosImport.ImportUploadService.ImportUploadServiceClient.CLIIkarosImport.ImportUploadService.IImportUploadService.UploadFile(FileUploadMessage
> request) in C:\projekte_c#\CLIIkarosImport\CLIIkarosImport\Service
> References\ImportUploadService\Reference.cs:line 194    at
> CLIIkarosImport.ImportUploadService.ImportUploadServiceClient.UploadFile(Int64
> FileSize, String OriginalFileName, String UserIpV4, String UserIpV6,
> String UserName, Stream FileStream, String& FileId, String& Message)
> in C:\projekte_c#\CLIIkarosImport\CLIIkarosImport\Service
> References\ImportUploadService\Reference.cs:line 205    at
> CLIIkarosImport.Webservice.Import.ImportServiceModule.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__2(Object
> x) in
> C:\projekte_c#\CLIIkarosImport\CLIIkarosImport\Webservice\Import\ImportServiceModule.cs:line
> 86

```
         Get["/ImportFromPublicLocation/{path}"] = x =>
         {
                string newPath = x.path;
                newPath = newPath.Replace("-*-", ".");
                newPath = newPath.Replace("-#-", @"\");

                var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(newPath);    
                Console.WriteLine($"Given path is {path}");

                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File doesn't exist!");
                    return new Response() {StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent};
                }

                var response = new CustomResponse();

                using (var client = new ImportUploadServiceClient())
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
                    var fStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

                    string id, message;
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
                    try
                    {
                        var fResponse = client.UploadFile(fStream.Length, fileName, "", "", "Import", fStream, out id, out message);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Response is {fResponse}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        throw;
                    }
                    
                    response.JobId = id;
                    response.Message = message;
                }

                return new JsonResponse<CustomResponse>(response, defaultJsonSerializer);
            };
```

I don't know if the change to https is the issue, or the move to the new server. I don't know if my predecessor did any changes to the old machine to make it work.

Let me know, if you need any further information.

EDIT:
I think its an issue within the application itself. I get the same Exception if the webserver is shut down and I can't find any calls to the api-server in wireshark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it was a security issue in user authentication with STS (AD FS or FS-STS) and I had to use classes from a DLL provided by the service provider to connect to the service.